# Unexpected error with creating firebase login and registration form

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am setting up my first mobile app using flutter and firebase. I recently started with the login and registration module using firebase_auth. Although I am convinced I have followed the instructions well, I still seem to run in the same problem regarding firebase.

I tried updating my GradleWrapper to the latest version: 5.4-all and kotlin version 1.3.30. I deleted several earlier versions of my app and retracted all my steps several times over but cannot seem to find a solution by my own.

I followed the error message to what I think might be the issue. android/src/main/java/io.flutter.plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FirebaseCorePlugin;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 */
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
      return;
    }
    FirebaseAuthPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin"));
    FirebaseCorePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FirebaseCorePlugin"));
  }

  private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    final String key = GeneratedPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
    if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
      return true;
    }
    registry.registrarFor(key);
    return false;
  }
}
```

both firebase plugins symbols cannot be resolved.

```
C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.437], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (10 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:/Users/----/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/---/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 183.5901
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.33.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\----\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.25.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • HTC 10 • FA726BN00007 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

error message

```
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: package androidx.annotation
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:754: error: cannot find symbol
  private void reportException(Result result, @Nullable Exception exception) {
                                               ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:658: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.SignInCompleteListener
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:677: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.TaskVoidCompleteListener
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:695: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin.GetSignInMethodsCompleteListener
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                              ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:540: error: cannot find symbol
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                                      ^
  symbol: class NonNull
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.8.4+5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:607: error: cannot find symbol
          public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                                          ^
  symbol: class NonNull
9 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



BUILD FAILED in 6s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
******************************************************************************************
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did not enable AndroidX in your project. Go to the gradle-properties (yourApp/android/gradle.properties) and insert following:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: it works!! you are an absolute lifesaver. Thank you so much

Comment: Already automatically had these fields, this solution didn't work for me.